# How can I play multiple sounds at once in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, core-audio

How can I play multiple sounds at once in the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found if you don't require any advanced audio features `AVAudioPlayer` and `NSOperationQueue` work quite nicely.

*NB: This example is adapted form a project and might contain some bugs*

```
//sound1 and sound2 are NSData objects

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;

AVAudioPlayer *player1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sound1 error:&error];
AVAudioPlayer *player2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sound2 error:&error];

if(error)
{
    //Handle errors...
}

NSInvocationOperation *op1 = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playSounds:) object:player1] autorelease];

NSInvocationOperation *op2 = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playSounds:) object:player2] autorelease];

[queue addOperation:op1];
[queue addOperation:op2];
```

The `playSounds` methods will look something like this:

```
- (void)playSounds:(id)data
{
    AVAudioPlayer *player = (AVAudioPlayer *)data;

    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
}
```

**A note on efficiency**, this will work fine on the simulator but the expensive operation on the device is the creation of the `AVAudioPlayer` object, i.e.:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sound1 error:&error];
```

Therefore it is best to have all your sounds in one file and use the `currentTime` property and the `play` and `stop` methods, to play the correct section of the sound file.

Comment: Is it really documented to be safe to access the AVAudioPlayer from another thread like this? /me == surprised

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://sites.google.com/site/iphonecoreaudiodevelopment/audio-units-and-the-augraph) is an example using AudioUnits. they might be a little complicated for your requirements, but then you never stated your requirements.